# Routing problem with a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I defined two action links in my view like below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Baxter", "SearchAffaires", new { LabelName = "Baxter" })
@Html.ActionLink("Favorite", "SearchAffaires", new { OnlyFavorite = true })
```

I defined the two routes below:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        "Search Affaire Only Label", // Route name
        "{controller}/Label/{LabelName}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Affaire", action = "SearchAffaires" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        "Search Affaire Only Favorite", // Route name
        "{controller}/Favorite", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Affaire", action = "SearchAffaires", OnlyFavorite = true } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

If I start my solution and point to my 'favorite' link, I get the following url:

http://localhost:3817/Affaire/Favorite

That's ok for me. Now, I restart my solution (important) and I point to a 'label' link (for this example, my label is Baxter), I get the following url:

http://localhost:3817/Affaire/Label/Baxter

That's ok for me. Now I didn't restart my solution and I point to my 'favorite' link, I get the following url:

http://localhost:3817/Affaire/Label/Baxter?OnlyFavorite=True

As you can see, the parameter named OnlyFavorite is passed again but I didn't expect that!

What can I do to avoid this behavour?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see any `{OnlyFavorite}` token in your route definitions, you only have `{LabelName}` in your first route definition.

Comment: @Darin: I placed the parameter 'OnlyFavorite = true' in the default parameters of the 'favorite' route. Don't you see it? Maybe that's the wrong way?! But anyway it works...(anyway the first time)

Comment: what you place in the defaults must also be present in the url (a.k.a the second argument). For example if you look at the default route that VS generates you will see that the `{id}` token is part of the url and then used in the defaults.

Comment: @Darin: I didn't know that the default parameters must also be present in the url. I'll try to refactor my routes... Next I'll edit my question to expose my changes. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the time you add the link MVC has no way of knowing which route you want to use, as it has all the parameters from the current request, `LabelName` is set, so it matches on the `Search Affaire Only Label` route.

Here's a fix. likewise you could alternatively add a constraint that `LabelName` can't be empty, so it matches on the second route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search Affaire Only Label",
    "{controller}/Label/{LabelName}",
    new { controller = "Affaire", action = "SearchAffaires" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Search Affaire Only Favorite",
    "{controller}/Favorite",
    new
    {
        controller = "Affaire",
        action = "SearchAffaires",
        LabelName = string.Empty,
        OnlyFavorite = true
    }
);

@Html.ActionLink("Baxter", "SearchAffaires", 
                 new { LabelName = "Baxter" })
@Html.ActionLink("Favorite", "SearchAffaires", 
                 new { LabelName = string.Empty, OnlyFavorite = true })
```

Comment: I need the parameter OnlyFavorite = true for the 'favorite' link but only for this one.

Comment: So what are you expecting the link to look like, it's not defined in your route, and True is the default.

Comment: I would like my links to look as I explain above: for the 'favorite' >> .../Affaire/Favorite and for a 'label' >> .../Affaire/Label/Baxter or .../Affaire/Label/GSK

Comment: Just tested this and it works, you just need to define `LabelName` in your other route, and explicitly set it to empty when creating the link.